# Python - Selenium Element returning "None"

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to create a small script to tell me if addresses need a certain type of shipping.

I have a list of addresses to input into a website and it will return what type they are. Why is this returning none, even though when I check the element in selenium it's there? And technically it has to be there, to even pass the "EC.presence_of_element_located" code.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('courier_website')

field = browser.find_element_by_id("txt-address-auto-complete")

field.send_keys("12 test Street")

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='ui-menu-item']/a[contains(@id, 'ui-id-')]")))

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']/a[contains(@id, 'ui-id-')]").click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="delivery-details-addresstype" and text() != ""]')))

post = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="delivery-details-addresstype"]').get_attribute('value')

print(post)
```

Output is "None"

HTML I'm trying to get the text out of

```
<table class="delivery-details">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <th colspan="3" id="delivery-details-addresstype">Residential Delivery Zone Address</th>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: What is `None` is not the element, it's the attribute named `value` of that element

Comment: So how do I get the text inside the element?

Comment: That depends on the type of element you have. Maybe try also posting the related HTML

Comment: ahh ok sorry, updated the OP

Comment: Have you already tried `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` ?

Comment: no ... thankyou so much that worked! Everything I read did not suggest that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of browser.find_element_by_xpath(//required_path).get_attribute('value'), use:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(//required_path).get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases `'textContent'` has worked for me

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(//path).get_attribute('textContent')
```